# How to send LocationResult with last location to PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-fusedlocation

How can I send a `PendingIntent` with a `LocationResult`?

I wanted to use same `PendingIntent` I setup for receiving location changes to also receive the last location.

See the last lines in the code:

```
// Create pending intent for a service which received location changes
Intent locationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationIntentService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        getApplicationContext(),
        0,
        locationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

// Start listening to location changes
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, pendingIntent);

// Get last location
Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

// Send last location
if(lastLocation != null) {
   // How to send it to the pending intent?
   // Result result = LocationResult.create( ... )
   // pendingIntent.send(result)
}
```

Comment: You need to find out what extras are contained in an `Intent` from the `FusedLocationApi`. Then you can "simulate" that yourself by adding the same extras.

Comment: Thanks. Correct, the extras key is FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED but it has been deprecated for some reason. I see `LocationResult` has `hasResult(intent)` and `extractResults(intent)` to read from intent, but I can't see the other way around, how to set a `LocationResult` to intent extras. I see there's a `writeToParcel` but no idea how that can work

Comment: You should add debug logging and dump the `Intent` that you get from `FusedLocationApi`, then I can help you simulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the code for `LocationResult.extractResult(intent)` it is possible to see that `LocationResult` is nothing more than a `Parcelable` extra inserted in the `Intent` with a specific Id. The following Kotlin function inserts a `List<Location>` in a given `Intent` as a `LocationResult`

```
private const val EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT = "com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT"

@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.NONE)
fun insertResult(intent: Intent, locations: List<Location>) {
    val result = LocationResult.create(locations)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT, result)
}
```

*Note: `FusedLocationApi` has been deprecated and `FusedLocationProviderClient` should be used instead. I have applied the solution above to unit test the `BroadcastReceiver` receiving updates from `FusedLocationProviderClient`*